# Unicode characters in LaTeX, getting errors

Tags: pdftex, unicode

I am trying to include Unicode charters in LaTeX but I am getting error.
These are the characters ,`മല  + ആയിരുന്നു        =   മലയായിരുന്നു` . I need to include

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

I am getting following error:

```
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.27 മ
ല + ആയിരുന്നു : മലയായിരുന...
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ല not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I use [this font](http://malayalam.kerala.gov.in/index.php/Fonts)

Editor:

Texmaker 3.2

Any Clues?

Comment: Well not all chars are supported, and not all chars are available in fonts.

Comment: So what I have to do?

Comment: Show us, which font you are using, which routine you use to compile, what packages you load, which encoding you have in your editor. Give us an MWE!

Comment: @LaRiFaRi is talking about a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this type of document, I would recommend to use [XeTeX](http://xetex.sourceforge.net/) which has builtin Unicode support. You will also need to load a font that has support for the needed characters. For example, try this with 'FreeSans':

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{FreeSans}

\begin{document}
മല + ആയിരുന്നു = മലയായിരുന്നു
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `xelatex unicode-test.tex` to get the result:

[image]